# Función waypoint

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy haciendo que cuando llega a una posición el scroll que es al llegar a la etiqueta `#menuStick` , el aspecto de CSS cambie de tamaño, pero necesito que si vuelve a subir hacia arriba el scroll vuelva a su posición natural.

//script//

```
  $('#menuStick').waypoint(function(){
    $('.fondoSHRh5').css("padding","8px");
    $('.fondoSHRh5').css("font-size","1.15rem");
    $('.fondoSHRh5').css("transition","1.25s all ease-in-out");
    $('.fondoDERMAh5').css("padding","8px");
    $('.fondoDERMAh5').css("font-size","1.15rem");
    $('.fondoDERMAh5').css("transition","1.25s all ease-in-out");
  },{
    offset: '0%'
  });
```

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar el plugin que usas para el `.waypoint`?

Comment: Uso la biblioteca simplemente, no estoy en wordpress ni nada.. `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes comprobar si el scroll es hacia abajo o hacia arriba:

```
$('#menuStick').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if(direction=="up") {
        //instrucciones cuando se hace scrooll hacia arriba
    } else {
        //instrucciones cuando se hace scrooll hacia abajo
    }
});
```

Así dependiendo de la dirección haces una cosa u otra.

Comment: Buenas gracias por tu ayuda @alexval pero como hago las condiciones, por lo que entiendo ahí esto solo comprueba la dirección del scroll, un saludo

Comment: Ya te lo he editado para que lo veas.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @alexval pero después del `else` le falta un `{` lo iba a modificar yo pero no son los caracteres suficientes para una edición. Gracias!

Comment: De nada, ya lo he modificado